# Is there a way to trim newlines out of a twig string?

Tags: symfony, twig, trim

I'm using objects in my view that I recover from a iCalendar file, these objects have string attributes, named description, and some of these strings contain "\n", and for some multiple times  and I can't seem to find a way to trim them out.

I've tried to trim them using the php function in the controller, however they still are there after the function.
Same for the trim function in Twig.
I am maybe using wrong parameters in these functions.

```
{{ coursCourant.description|split("(")[0]|split(".")[0] }} <BR>
```

This displays something like "\n\nPromo S4\n" when the expected result is the same thing but without the multiple "\n".
I'm using splits on a ( and on a . because some strings contains them and I don't need to display the parts after those.

Answer (score 1):

`trim` will only remove trailing and ending whitespaces.

- Use `str_replace` in your controller (recommended)

`$content = str_replace("\n", '', $content);`

- Use `replace` in your template

`{{ foo|replace({"\n":'',}) }}`

---

*hence the double quotes to remove an actual newline character*